# GWT & JSNI. $doc.getElementById return null

Tags: gwt, applet, jsni

I am trying to call a *document* Javascript'method to recover an applet (id:DesglosaApplet). In the class where I implement **onModuleLoad** (the main class) I put:

```
    public native void visualize(String city) {
       var applet = $doc.getElementById("DesglosaApplet");
       if (applet != null) {
          applet.visualizeTowers(city);
          alert("NOT NULL");
       }
       else 
          alert("NULL");
    }
```

It is works, applet is not null. But if I do the shame **in another class** (this second class called by main class) **it doesn't work**: I have tried `$wnd.$doc`, `$wnd.$($doc)`, `$doc.applets["DesglosaApplet"]`... `var applet` is always null. I do not forget add in the class:

```
    HTML applet = new HTML();
    applet.setHTML("<applet code=\"org.jdesktop.applet.util.JNLPAppletLauncher\"" +
    "codebase=\"./\"" + "id=\"DesglosaApplet\"" +   ...  );
```

I am working with GWT and JSNI. I want to call an applet method in another class than that implements EntryPoint interface,

```
var applet = doc.getElementById("IdApplet");
```

**Is it possible to use "$doc." in a class other than that implements Entrypoint interface?**

Comment: Yes it is possible.  Your error must be somewhere else.

Comment: Ok funkybro, so I assume that error must be in objetc document. How can I get the document which I have added the applet and do not other? ( I think that I am recovering other document, that`s why var applet is null).

Comment: Try something simple first, like adding a named div, and see if you can access that.  Also try iterating through the properties in `$doc` and see if they are as you would expect.

Comment: thanks for the fast answer. I`ll try it.

Comment: I have tried adding '<p id=\"a\">Prueba de etiqueta</p>' and later in native method 'var e = $doc.getElementById("a")'  **e is null** again. So I think the problem is that I recover other 'document' Is it possible?

Comment: Like I said, try iterating through all the properties like so: `for (var i in $doc) { console.log("$doc." + i + " = " + $doc[i]); }` and see if the results are as you would expect.  Also, try creating a **new, empty GWT project** and see if you can reproduce the error.  I think your problem is probably elsewhere.

Comment: I deleted a dependency in the POM file (it is a Maven proect) and it works.